# optional(text.verifying("エラーメッセージ"))からエラーメッセージを取得できない

Tags: scala, playframework

現在scalaでフォーム画面からポストされるデータのバリデーション機能を実装しています。
Formの定義を以下のようにしています。

`optional(text.verifying("姓をを入力してください", lastName => !lastName.isEmpty()))`

入力されない場合、エラーメッセージを取得して画面に表示したいのですが、どうやって取得するのでしょうか？

Comment: playframeworkでしょうか？Scala自体やPlayのversionなど、もう少し詳細な情報を書くと回答がつきやすくなると思います

Comment: play framework 2.3 
scala 2.11.5 になります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play Framework2.x系のご質問であってますでしょうか？

また、入力エラーにならない、というご質問でしょうか？
それともview側でどうやってメッセージを取得すればよいか、というご質問でしょうか？

Play2で前者という仮定で回答しますと optional() を使うのを止めるのがよいと思います。
また、必須な文字列項目であれば nonEmptyText という mapping が定義されているので、
nonEmptyText を使うと良いと思います。

「姓を入力してください」 というエラー文言については、conf/messages でコントロールする方がお勧めです。

Comment: 迅速な回答に恐縮です。

色々言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。
play framework 2.3です。
質問内容は後者のほうになります。

optional()が使用しないほうがいいというのは、どういうことでしょうか?
None.getが起こるから？

Comment: optional という Mapping はそもそも有っても無くてもいい値に対して使うものなので、必須チェックを行う様な項目に使うのは不適切に思われます。

view 側でどう表示させるか、ですが、 view helper を使う場合と使わない場合でだいぶ変わるので、まず view側をどう作っているかご提示頂いた方が話がはやいかと思います。

Comment: たしかにそうですね。ご教示ありがとうございます。

色々試してみたところ、

@Messages(form("{フォームのキー}").error.get.message
で出来ました。
ご返信、とても参考になりました。ありがとうございます。